# Deploying my custom Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-domain-api

I have been searching for an answer, more that likely using the wrong terminology, to my question and I have read through the Google documentation but I am now more confused than when I started looking for the answer.

I'm new to Google Apps and a complete beginner at Javascript. I recently started working in a Google Apps school (we have our own domain) and I have started developing some custom Google Sheets to aid other teachers and boost productivity.

I have developed a Sheet with some custom scripts and a custom menu bar to call the various functions of the script. Since I am so new to Javascript my scripts have some bugs that I fix as other users report them to me. However, my problem is that when I fix a bug in my "master" Sheet the end user must open the shared master Sheet and make a copy of it to benefit from the update. I want to update to be pushed out to all copies of the sheet (circa 4 copies)

I know need to deploy it but I don't know whether I need to deploy it as a web app or a sheets add-on from the script editor? Again, we have our own domain so I do believe I don't need to have it approved by Google to use it internally in our domain?

Comment: From the sound of it, you need to publish an add-on, since the goal is to help users manage own spreadsheets. Web apps is something else; it's using a script to power a website that users access, like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish), public add-ons require a review before publication, since you have your own domain, **you can publish just for users within your domain without a review**.

To publish an add-on for the first time, follow [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#prepare_and_deploy_your_add-on). If you also want to let Google Apps domain administrators install and authorize your add-on for all users in their domain, follow the steps for [domain-wide publication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide) as well.

When you fixed your bugs and wanted it to be updated to all copies of sheets, you can follow this [Update your add-on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#update_your_add-on) link to update an add-on that you have already published.

> 1. Open the add-on project in the script editor.
> 2. Make the necessary changes to your code, then save a new version of your project by clicking **File > Manage versions**, then **Save
>      New Version**. Close the Manage Versions dialog.
> 3. Click **Publish > Deploy as add-on**. (Or Sheets or Docs or Forms add-on.)
> 4. In the dialog that appears, change the add-on's details as needed, select the new version of your script, then click **Update store
>      item**. (If you change the add-on's name, make sure you also change
>      the name of the Apps Script project to match, as the project name is
>      shown in the authorization dialog.)
> 5. In the store listing, click **Publish changes**, then click **OK** in the dialog that appears.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that helps a lot.. I will look at deploying it internally first..

Many thanks..